# How do I fix a text box in my quiz model?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with my quiz module which I am currently doing. I have a problem with the fact that if I enter the correct but also the wrong solution in the text input box, I will not see the text stating whether I won or lost. It doesn't write anything to me in the debug console, so I need to deal with the error. Below I attach js and html code. There is also a picture to the code which is quite important in the quiz, but I will not give it here because in my opinion it is useless.

And I also apologize for the fact that it is not English but it is Czech :)

JS Code:

```
function check(){

    var question1 = document.question1;
    var question2 = document.question2;
    var correct = 0;

    if (question1 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Semily,Stará Paka,Libuň") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question2 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Turnov,Libuň") {
        correct++;
    }   

    if (correct == 1) {
        answerElement.innerHTML = "Špatně!";
    }

    if (correct == 2) {
        answerElement.innerHTML = "Správně!";
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="module">

    Zadej řešení a): <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "question1" class="question1">
    </br>
    Zadej řešení b): <input id = "textbox2" type = "text" name = "question2" class="question2">
    </br>
    <input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Odeslat řešení." onclick = "check()">
    </br>
    </br>
    <p style="font-size:20px;" class="answerElement"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```js
function check(){

    var question1 = document.getElementsByClassName("question1")[0].value;
    var question2 = document.getElementsByClassName("question2")[0].value;
    var correct = 0;

    if (question1 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Semily,Stará Paka,Libuň") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question2 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Turnov,Libuň") {
        correct++;
    }   

    if (correct == 1) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("answerElement")[0].innerHTML = "Špatně!";
    }

    if (correct == 2) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("answerElement")[0].innerHTML = "Správně!";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="module">

    Zadej řešení a): <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "question1" class="question1">
    </br>
    Zadej řešení b): <input id = "textbox2" type = "text" name = "question2" class="question2">
    </br>
    <input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Odeslat řešení." onclick = "check()">
    </br>
    </br>
    <p style="font-size:20px;" class="answerElement"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

```
var question1 = document.question1;
```

is not right. Javascript will see `document.question1` as a variable. (same thing with question2) To get the value of an element, do something like

```
var question1 = document.querySelector('question1').value;
```

Same goes for the answer:

```
    answerElement.innerHTML = "Správně!";
```

should be

```
    document.querySelector('answerElement').innerHTML = "Správně!";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but it still doesn't work for me, @John Tyner

Answer (score 0):

The output is not what you expecting, because you did not select the element properly in javascript.

I've changed you code a bit, and it works now.

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function check() {

            var question1 = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
            var question2 = document.getElementById('textbox2').value;
            var answerElement = document.getElementById('answerElement');

            var correct = 0;

            if (question1 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Semily,Stará Paka,Libuň") {
                correct++;
            }
            if (question2 == "Tanvald,Železný Brod,Turnov,Libuň") {
                correct++;
            }

            if (correct == 1) {
                answerElement.innerText = "Špatně!";
                
            }

            if (correct == 2) {
                answerElement.innerText = "Správně!";
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="module">

        Zadej řešení a): <input id="textbox" type="text" name="question1" class="question1">
        </br>
        Zadej řešení b): <input id="textbox2" type="text" name="question2" class="question2">
        </br>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Odeslat řešení." onclick="check()">
        </br>
        </br>
        <p style="font-size:20px;" id="answerElement" class="answerElement"></p>
</div>
```

You may also notice that I've used id to select the html element in the function, because the answerElement `<p id="answerElement></p>` may probably be the only element in the page to do what it's doing. id is used for that exact reason.